# update array when the user updates the text field in the cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I was wondering if there's a way to update `barcodeItemsQuantity` array when the user updates the text field in a custom `uitableviewcell`. Below are my code snippets. and I want to update data from my array whenever the user changes the textfield from the custom tableviewcell.

viewcontroller.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Cell Initialized");
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"BarcodeItemsCell";

    BarcodeItemsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[BarcodeItemsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    if (indexPath.row == [barcodeItems count]) {
        // Add new row
        cell.barcodeLabel.text = @"scan SKU";
        cell.barcodeLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"barcodeIcon"];
        [cell.leftButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell.leftButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.quantityTextField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        [cell.leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(scanBarcode) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        NSLog(@"Add another Item Requested");
    }
    else {
        // Display barcode items
        cell.barcodeLabel.text = [barcodeItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"deleteIcon"];
        cell.leftButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [cell.leftButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell.leftButton.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell.leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteRow:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [barcodeItemsQuantity addObject:cell.quantityTextField];
    }

    NSLog(@"Cell Populated");
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return true;
}

-(void) deleteRow:(id)sender {
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:photoCaptureView.itemsTableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [photoCaptureView.itemsTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    [barcodeItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [photoCaptureView.itemsTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    NSLog(@"Item Removed");
}
```

barcodeitestableviewcell.h

```
@interface BarcodeItemsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *leftButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *barcodeLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *quantityTextField;


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can update your data model value for the textfield text placed inside custom table cell.

**STEP 1:**

Add delegate in your current class "UITextFieldDelegate"

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate
```

**STEP 2:**

on your "cellForRowAt indexPath" invoke the delegate to current textfield and also add the tag

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    // add the following lines
 cell.textField.delegate = self
 cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell
}
```

**STEP 3:**

call the UITextField Delegates

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
if !textField.text.isEmpty {    // check textfield contains value or not
    if textField.tag == 0 {
        firstName = textField.text!
    } else {
        lastName = textField.text!
    }
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {
    if textField.tag == 0 {
        firstName = ""
    } else {
        lastName = ""
    }
}
```

Here, you can replace the firstName and lastName with your desired model variables.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks this surely helped me.

Comment: Your welcome @jordanzee, In case of any issue please comment and don't forget to vote the answer.